# How I can fix wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content problem?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I got a problem with Wordpress since 3 weeks.

I dont know why I get this error and want to fix it.

The CMS is Wordpress version: 4.3.19

Wordpress gives me the following error message:

- Notice: wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content Filter/Aktion ist seit Version WPSEO 3.0 veraltet! Benutze stattdessen javascript. in wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3517

English:

- Notice: wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content is deprecated since version WPSEO 3.0! Use javascript instead.

I thought it caused by the "Yoast SEO" Plugin but im not sure.

How I can fix this error?

Best Regards

Comment: https://developer.yoast.com/yoast-seo-breaking-api-changes/

Answer (score 0):

The current Yoast SEO plugin version is 10.0, and WordPress 5.1.1. I would advice updating WordPress and yoast seo to their latest versions and try again, good chance this will solve your problem.